# Know whether the shell script contains syntax error without running the script

Tags: scripts

I have a long shell script containing a lot of conditions and I want to know whether there is any syntax error in the script without running it.

Since shell script is interpreted I think it is not possible but is there a way to know by using some trick.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
bash -n scriptname
```

Although, this will check syntax, not command availability. (will not warn if script uses a command that is not installed yet)

Comment: In addition to `bash`'s inbuilt syntax checḱing you can use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to identify less severe issues and bad practices.

Answer (score 5):

I found an online tool to check the syntax of the script. In addition to checking the script, also suggests possible corrections to avoid errors.

[Check shell script online](http://www.shellcheck.net/)